# DMIN in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My db is used to calculate commissions due to a salesperson. The commission percentage is tiered so that it increases as the total sales increase. For example, a salesperson is paid 2% if they hit $100 in sales, 3% if they hit $500, 4% if they hit $1000, etc.

The db has two tables used to calculate a salesperson's commission.

- **Sales** records all the sales made and has two fields: **[Salesperson]** which identifies who made the sale and **Value** which logs the total amount of the sale.
- **CommissionRates** has a tiered commission structure based on the total amount sold in a time period and has two fields: **[Max Amount]** which identifies the upper limit for a rate tier and **[Rate]** which gives the percentage due when total sales are above the related [Max Amount].

I need to create a query (or vba output to a table) combining these two tables that returns the earned commission amount per salesperson, calculated total sales in a given time period multiplied by the maximum rate for sales achieved.

I'm stumped. I've tried several ways to use a DMIN function but repeatedly get an "unknown" response when executing the query. The code following code works perfectly when I replace `Sum([Sales].[value])` with a fixed number, but fails with the "unknown" error using the variable.

```
Sum([Sales].[Value])*DMin("Rate","CommissionRates","[Max_Amount] >=Sum([Sales].[Value])"
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is that there is no built-in DMIN function in Access.  I can't write out a full example for you right now, but my first thought is to just do it in a subquery. In other words, make a completely separate query that groups the minimum of your value by salespersonID.  Then left join from your main query onto that query.  Have you tried that method yet?

Comment: @PowerUser: There certainly is a DMin function (https://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/access-help/dmin-dmax-functions-HA001228826.aspx).

Comment: @VBlades, I stand corrected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a variable concatenation error.  Try this:

```
DMin("Rate","CommissionRates","[Max_Amount] >= " & Sum([Sales].[Value]))
```